# Must set class in order for posterior's summarise_draws() output to display correctly in RMD

Tags: r, brms

I am using the `summarise_draws()` function within the R `posterior` package within an R Markdown. When calling the function on a draws object (the samples from the posterior distribution of a brms model) in a markdown, the output is a tibble containing columns with data type `S3: pillar_num`. The values in these columns are not readable. However, when the same code is run in the console, there is no issue with the output. Below is the code that works in the console but not the RMD code chunk:

```
library(posterior)
x <- example_draws("eight_schools")
summarise_draws(x)
```

Output in Markdown:

[image]

Output in Console:

[image]

I have found a workaround to this. Setting the class of the `summarise_draws()` output  to `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")` wihtin a code chunk of the RMD remedies this problem:

```
x <- example_draws("eight_schools")
x <- summarise_draws(x)
class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
x
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Also, when a variable is acessed individually in an RMD code chunk like `summarise_draws(x)$q5`  the output is normal:

[image]

Is anyone aware of 1) why, without changing the class, the output is different between the console and the RMD code chunk? And 2) why setting the class explicitly, as done in the above example, fixes the issue?

Comment: But when you knit it, do you get the same issue?

Comment: @Golem No, when I knit it the output is correct as it is in the console